# How to write data after changing Excel column order to a text file in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I would like to write to a text file from Excel, but the data order is different from the column order in Excel. For Example:

```
Excel Column : Col1,   Col2,   Col3,   Col4,   Col5    
Text file    : Col1,   Col2,   Col5,   Col4,   Col3
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: make a copy of the current sheet and change the column order within the copy before saving. When you don't need the copy then any more, delete it.

Comment: Comment from @adsy2010: `You could even make a macro to resort the second sheet #` (adsy2010, you now have enough rep to comment, please re-submit it as one and I will delete this placeholder).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answer.
I developed the following way of doing it:

**Code:**

```
For i = 1 To LastRow

    For j = 2 To 10
            Select Case j
            Case 3
                 strCellValue = Trim(shSheetName.Cells(i, j + 2).Value)
            Case 5
                 strCellValue = Trim(shSheetName.Cells(i, j - 2).Value)
            Case Else
                 strCellValue = Trim(shSheetName.Cells(i, j).Value)
            End Select
    Next j
        'Process of Write [strCellValue] to text file
Next i
```